# Why are static files from AWS S3 not loading?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have hosted my static files on Amazon bucket and configured them in settings but still they are not loading when I run the server and throwing the error as shown in the image:

[image: errors]

Comment: are you retrieve normal files link or presigned url and show me the settings.py

Comment: Are you wanting these files to be accessible to anyone on the Internet at any time? I notice that you are using a Signed URL. Is this intentional? How is the HTML page being generated?

Comment: bro html pages are on local machine..and css,js and images are in the bucket which i made pubic @John Rotenstein

Comment: bro i dont understand what exactly you are saying..can u explain clearly plz@giveJob

Answer (score 1):

Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default.

If you wish for your objects to be accessible, you will need to use one of these methods:

- Attach a **Bucket Policy** to your Amazon S3 bucket that permits public access. See: [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-2), *or*
- Assign `public-read` permissions to the **individual objects**, *or*
- Have your application generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which grants time-limited access to an object.

The screenshot you provided shows URLs that in the format of a **pre-signed URL**. This is either because your application generated the pre-signed URL, or because you copied a link from within the Amazon S3 management console. These URLs expire after a given time period, which is ideal for security if you are providing temporary access to a private object.

However, if your intention is that these files should be accessible to anyone at any time, you should attach a **Bucket Policy** to the Amazon S3 bucket.

See also: [Hosting a static website on Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html)